# Weird Issue with JComponent Visibility

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I am working on a GUI project with Swing in Java and the program is generally working fine. However, under each screen, I have a back button that calls the method of the screen before it and goes through the ArrayList containing all of the elements on the current screen and calls setVisible(false) on them. Upon running the program, the back button works correctly if you click it once but if you go back on the screen, and click it again, it takes two clicks for it to correctly work and then four clicks and then eight clicks and so on. I have no idea what is going on or why it is behaving this way as nothing in my code seems to do it. Also, sometimes, the button correctly returns to the previous screen but then keeps the components on the current screen active as if setVisible(false) was never called. The following code represents the general structure of my project. Is there anything that it is doing that is generating this problem?

```
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

 import javax.swing.*;
 public class MAIN {
static JFrame frame;
static JPanel panel;
 public static void main(String [] args) {
    mainScreen();

}
 public static void mainScreen() {
      JButton newScreen = new JButton("Next Screen");
      frame = new JFrame();
      panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setBounds(0,0,1920,1080);
      panel.setBackground(Color.cyan);

    newScreen.setBounds(50, 500, 100, 500);

    newScreen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
        
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             newScreen.setVisible(false);
             JButton returnButton = new JButton("return");
                     returnButton.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 100);
                     panel.add(returnButton);
                     returnButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                             returnButton.setVisible(false);
                             mainScreen();
                         }
                     });
             
             }
         });

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
panel.add(newScreen);
frame.add(panel);        
frame.setSize(1920,1080);
frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setVisible(true);



     }


      }
```

Comment: *"goes through the ArrayList"* What array list? 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  ..

Comment: .. Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 4) Please [edit] the question to expand or update information, rather than [deleting the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65279590/418556) & starting over.

Comment: The suggestion in your last question was to 1) start a class name with an upper case character and 2) follow the standards of the JDK for class names. Do you know of any classes in the JDK that are completely capitalized?? Why is your class name completely capitalized???

Comment: All this code does is keep creating new JFrames. Don't create a new frame every time you return to the frame. Instead you may want to use a `CardLayout`. It will allow you to swap panels on the existing frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and a working example. It will also proved a better structure for your code. You should NOT be using static variables, this is an indication of poor design.